# Exchange Server Update Incoming Message

Tags: exchange-server, add-in, exchange-server-2010, exchange-server-2007, exchange-transport-agents

Does the newest version (or older versions for that matter) support some kind of custom add in (plug in module?) that can be written to analyze incoming messages and possibly replace the incoming message with a place holder or some new message we create?

I suppose another approach might be to build a folder watcher that looks for incoming messages files (which would be exchange messages) and then replace those messages?

I'm not an Exchange expert so if there's a better approach I'm all ears. We have a .NET assembly that can analyze the content that is used by an Outlook add in. I was just curious if there was a way to do a server side module that could do the same thing to incoming messages that we do to outgoing messages.

Answer (score 0):

The feature you are referring to is called Transport Agents. There are some libraries that ship with Exchange Server that allow you to create custom agents that can handle all inbound and outbound mail as you describe. Check out the following documentation:

[Transport agents in Exchange 2013](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dd877026%28v=exchg.150%29.aspx)

There are some basic sample applications associated with this documentation that you can download as well:

[Transport agent code samples for Exchange 2013](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dd877105%28v=exchg.150%29.aspx)

Even though these samples are part of the Exchange 2013 samples, the code should work fine with 2010 and 2007 with little or no modification as long as you have the appropriate libraries when you build the applications.

I hope this information helps. If this does resolve your question, please mark this post as answered.

Thanks,

--- Bob ---